# td-agent-bit delivers only after restart and then stops

Tags: tail, opensearch, fluent-bit, td-agent

In my Office I am forced to work still with td-agent-bit, an upgrade to the recent fluent-bit should be possible later this year.

I have trouble with the following configuration:

```
[INPUT]
    Name tail
    Path /ws/int/xxx/log/c/log/lvasc-xxx/import-management.log,/ws/int/xxx/log/c/log/lvasc-xxx/importer.log
    Path_Key On
    Tag ax_imports_c
    Parser ax_parser
    DB /home/pgostack/tail_c.db
    Buffer_Max_Size 250MB
    Refresh_Interval 10
[OUTPUT]
    Name opensearch
    Match ax_imports_c
    Host lvast-pgopbos01
    Port 9200
    Index imports_index
    Type  imports_type
    HTTP_User cccc
    HTTP_Passwd cccccc!
    tls On
    tls.verify Off
    Suppress_Type_Name On
    Logstash_Format On
    Logstash_Prefix ax_imports_c
```

When I start it works like a charm and sends all the log-data to OpenSearch - but then stopps.
Only when I restart td-agent-bit it sends the data (filling the gap) to OS.
I tried all the parameters I can think of, but still the same. Another conf with an exec-routine works without flaws...

Help & hints would be very welcome!

Greetings from Germany

Thomas (bearbeitet)

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the `Buffer_Max_Size` value, which could be too high for the volume of logs your data source produces. In fact, the data won't be sent until the buffer is full or until the agent is restarted, whatever happens first

Comment: Thanks! But when I disable the Buffer_Max_Size debug shows, that it cant's process the (sometimes very large) logs and does nothing. When I change to 96k (default is 32k) I see no difference: Data is sent to OpenSearch only after (re-)start!

Comment: I see, was there anything interesting in the agent logs when you had the original `Buffer_Max_Size` value?

Comment: While the import log in use is growing and growing, all I see in the fluentbit-log is:

[2023/03/16 08:15:17] [debug] [input:tail:tail.4] scanning path /path/to/my/logs/myserver/import-management.log
[2023/03/16 08:15:17] [debug] [input:tail:tail.4] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /path/to/my/logs/myserver/import-management.log, inode 48385809
[2023/03/16 08:15:17] [debug] [input:tail:tail.4] 0 new files found on path '/path/to/my/logs/myserver/import-management.log'
[2023/03/16 08:15:17] [debug] [input:tail:tail.4] scanning path /path/to/my/logs/myserver/importer.log

Comment: [2023/03/16 08:15:17] [debug] [input:tail:tail.4] scan_blog add(): dismissed: /path/to/my/logs/myserver/importer.log, inode 48385929
[2023/03/16 08:15:17] [debug] [input:tail:tail.4] 0 new files found on path '/path/to/my/logs/myserver/importer.log'

Path edited - it's not really "/path/to/my/logs/myserver/" ;-)

Comment: Looks like fluentbit doesn't realize that there are additional lines and therefor ignores the logs...

Comment: mh, just as a test, can you try to add the `Read_From_Head On` option to your input config to see if the log file is read again?

Comment: Read_From_Head On didn't change anything...

Comment: ran out of ideas, sounds like a bug, i would try to see what happens with different agent versions…possibly an upgrade would help